# JavaFx TableView Multiple Cursor Editing

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

There a way to use the Multiple Cursor Editing like notepad++ on multiple cells at once in a TableView?
Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Can you provide an image or something so we can full understand what multi-caret editing and what you want to achieve?

Comment: This but in a table column
https://s18.postimg.org/e5sjpsc6x/CARETS.png

Comment: The image did not help me understand what is being asked here.

Comment: What I hope this helps you understand:
https://files.readme.io/eTvjalnGSd5wwMMM7X3g_multiplecursors.gif
imagines that the div are in the cell and I want to change them, as shown in gif